# I am having an issue calling a method for the area of a rectangle

Tags: java, class, methods, constructor

I have the getters and setters, default and overloaded constructors, toString and my area method on my Rectangle class. My RectangleTest is just my values and output statements. I have been trying to get my area method working but there is no calling of my height and width, no matter what I try.

```
public class Rectangle {
public double width ;
private double height; 
private String color ;
private double area;

public double getWidth ( ) { return width; }
public void setWidth ( double w ) {
this.width = w; } 
public double getHeight ( ) {return height; }
public void setHeight ( double h ) { 
this.height = h; } 

public String getColor ( ) {return color; }

public void setColor ( String co ) { 
this.color = (co); } 

public Rectangle ( ) { 
height = 0;
width = 0;
color = (" ");
System.out.println("Default constructor");
//default constructor
}

public Rectangle ( double w, double h, String co) { 
width = w;
height = h;
color = (co);
System.out.println("Overloaded constructor" );
//overloaded constructor
} 
public double findArea (){
return area;
}
public void setArea (double width, double height){
area = width * height;   
}
public String toString ( ) {
String x = "Rectangle width is " + width + ", height is " + height +
    ", color is " + color + " and the area is " + area;
return x;
} 
}

public class RectangleTest {


public static void main(String[] args) {

Rectangle shape = new Rectangle(2.0, 4.0, "red");
Rectangle r2 = new Rectangle(2.0, 3.0, "Yellow");
Rectangle r3 = new Rectangle(2.0, 3.0, "Yellow");


do { r2.width++  ; 

} while (r2.width == (r3.width));

if (r2.equals (r3))
    System.out.println("r2 still equals r3" );
else
    System.out.println("r2 is now a square");

    System.out.println("First rectangle is " + shape );

    System.out.println("Second rectangle is " + r2 );

if (r2.equals (r3))
    System.out.println("\nShape 2 equals shape 3");
else
    System.out.println("\nShape 2 and 3 are not equal");

//System.exit(0);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`findArea` is a calculable result, this means that it's result is based on the result of calculating other values. Based on your code example, the only place `area` is calculated is when `setArea` is called, but `setArea` is never called.

A better solution would be to have `findArea` perform the calculation itself

```
public double findArea (){
    return width * height;
}
```

This has the benefit of not having you to remember to call the `setArea` method whenever the `width` or `height` changes

Answer (score 0):

Your Rectangles are not fully constructed, because the method `setArea(double width, double height)` is never called, leaving the area of all objects with the default value of 0.0..... you should call the method it in the constructor.

```
public Rectangle ( double w, double h, String co) { 
    width = w;
    height = h;
    color = (co);
    System.out.println("Overloaded constructor" );
    //overloaded constructor
   setArea (width, height);   ///here!
}
```

Note:
area can be calculated immediately with w and h, which are class members, no need to define a method

```
setArea (width, height);
```

using parameters that are in the same class, setArea() will be enough

Comment: Better update the `setWidth` and `setHeight` methods as well ;)

Answer (score 0):

The method to calculate the area `setArea` is never invoked. With the way you're code is going, you can put it in `toString`

```
public String toString ( ) {
   setArea(width, height);
   String x = "Rectangle width is " + width + ", height is " + height +
    ", color is " + color + " and the area is " + area;
   return x;
}
```

But your code is not the standard way of how it should be done.